# svn:ignore -only for ignoring during a commit or is it also during update?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I want to make sure that some ide project metadata files are not updated when I checkout from svn. Unfortunately it has been checked into the project when the project was created, but I have my own version of these files.

Will svn:ignore also ignore the file during update -ie., not update the file ? I am assuming its not going to be the case. If not, is there a way to tell svn to not update a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not checkout an older revision of the source tree into a new directory, modify one of the metadata files, do an `update`, and see what happens?

If nothing else, you should be able to assign all of the non-metadata files to a Subversion changeset and use the `--changeset` argument to specify that your `update`, etc commands should only operate on those files.

Comment: Thankyou that might work. Does subclipse of subversive provide a way to specify changeset ? I would like to be able to do that.

Comment: I haven't used either of those plugins, so I can't really say anything about them.  Most of my Subversion experience is using the command-line client.  Your best bet is to consult the documentation on the plugins' respective websites.

Answer (score 2):

Svn:ignore only affects untracked files. It does not affect files already tracked by svn, nor files explicit mentioned at the command line (for example `svn add *` will also add ignored files in a unix shell, since the * is interpreted by the shell, and thus override any active svn:ignore property).

You might want to delete or rename the project metadata file in the repository.